# What is the best times to ask a question?

Tags: discussion

When I need to ask a question, I want to reach the widest possible hearing so that more experts see my question. It gives me a better chance of finding the best answer.

I imagine that the best time is when more users are online, but I have no idea what time that is. 
Someone could give me more information?

Comment: I think this must have been asked at least once on MSO already.

Comment: ...... Never? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an old blog post about this, [The Best Time to Ask a Stack Overflow Question?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/)

I'm not sure the best time to ask is when the most people are on or not, though. Questions slide off the front page more quickly then, so your number of views might just stay the same. It would probably be more effective to look at the trends for a specific tag to find out when experts in your subject area are answering questions.