# Are Voting Habits Cultural?

Tags: discussion, voting, behavior

I live in South Africa and so I've discovered (from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268970)) the optimal time to ask a question is at about 5pm here because that's when user activity on SO picks up in the USA. Something I've recently begun wondering though is whether the cultural differences between say India, Africa & Europe and the Americas affect voting habits.

So, for example, if you're from Europe are you more likely to downvote?

If you're from Jamaica are you more likely to upvote? etc.

Does anyone know? I'm guessing the data is there to mine...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best times to ask a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268970/what-is-the-best-times-to-ask-a-question)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because that's more a question of when there are the most people active. I guess there's some overlap if you're looking for a particular type of reaction.

Comment: @jcuenod: I believe there was a Meta.SE post about this at some point; the conclusion is that there are some cultures where upvoting your colleagues is a social norm, but that's about it.

Comment: Well, Southern India certainly marches to a different drum, but that doesn't have much to do with voting for other people's post.  If you want a good answer then you should be more concerned with views than votes.  General pattern is that SO users ask questions in the morning and answer after lunch.  Super-impose the Earth's rotation and you'll find a peak at UTC 14:00 when Europe answers and UTC 21:00 for the Americas.

Comment: I'd be surprised to find there wasn't a time-based skew on voting, if only because I'm much more forgiving of the first inane question of the 'day' than the last....

Comment: I guess it comes to the total of moderating users on that time period, and it's related to total active users.